# For spin-off situations, where can I find information on insider participation?

Tags: sec, spin-off

I'm going through the Form 10-12B for the 2015 HP/HPE spin-off. I'm wondering where on the form I would find information on insider participation, for example I'd like to answer the following questions:

- Will the management of the spin-off be compensated with stock, and if
  so, how much?
- Will the parent company have any ownership in the spin-off, if so how
  much?

If this information is not in the Form 10 where would I find it?